# Web Audio API Inconsistent Unable to decode audio data DOMException

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, web-audio-api

Since yesterday I've been looking through all the SO posts with this error, and while I've tried some of the things suggested, none has resolved the problem. Because the error is inconsistent across types of streams it's been hard to track down a root cause. I'm hoping my sharing my question here maybe someone will see a pattern or have a solution.

- Firstly, locally hosted files and web-hosted steams are working fine inside HTML5 `audio` tags. See we can assume pathing is ok.
- Secondly, I also noticed the code below works as expected on my favorite internet radio station [WeFunkRadio](http://www.wefunkradio.com/), but I don't want to be pinging them as I develop an app for a completely different purpose.
- Public domain mp3s hosted in the Node.js server's `/public` folder with the below code however, consistently returns the error: `DOMException: Unable to decode audio data`

I've tried to strip the code down to the bare minimum needed to replicated the problem using a media from a [WikiCommons hosted public domain file](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:JesusWalkedThatLonesomeValley.ogg). I'm currently developing on the latest Chrome 85.0.4183.102.

```
StreamURL ='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/9/90/JesusWalkedThatLonesomeValley.ogg/JesusWalkedThatLonesomeValley.ogg.mp3',

const options = {
    headers: new Headers({ 'content-type': 'audio/mp3' }),
    mode: 'no-cors',
    cache: 'default',
};

const getAudioData = () =>
    fetch(StreamURL.url, options)
        .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then((arrayBuffer) => audioCtx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))

async function createAudioStream() {
    try {
        let playback = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
        playback.buffer = await getAudioData();
        playback.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        playback.start(0);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

audioContainer.addEventListener('click', createAudioStream);
```

One can see in the developer console network tab the data does get into the browser, however, it still returns the decoding error. The error right now is stopping me from doing further processing on the audio with the Web Audio API.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet is incomplete. I had to modify it a bit to make it run.

Put a `console.log(arrayBuffer)` before you call `decodeAudioData`. I get an empty `arrayBuffer`, so `decodeAudioData` naturally fails to decode.

I do not know why `arrayBuffer` is empty.

Comment: As Raymond said the ArrayBuffer is empty. Try using fetch without the options: `fetch(StreamURL.url)`. Setting the content-type to 'audio/mp3' means that you are going to send an MP3 file and not that you expect the server to return one.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if decodeAudioData could return more information about why it failed to decode?  Information like "buffer is empty", "don't know how to decode this type", "ill-formed file".  At least you get a hint at what might be wrong instead of just "FAIL".

Comment: Good info.. Still trying to track back the empty buffer.